# Android - Textview orientation in TableLayout's childs 0px + width attributes and UI changes

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, textview, tablelayout

I'm having issues with Android 4.3 (EDIT: IN ALL APIS) in a RelativeLayout with a TableLayout header, a LinearLayout scrollable body and a LinearLayout footer.
The body contains two webviews and the activity works perfectly with API level <18. When I run my application in API level 18 (either simulated by AVD or installed in my Galaxy Nexus), when the webViews load the content, the text of textViews in the TableLayout disappear, and only remain the first Character (or the first two charachters if the text is in two lines). It seems the webView change the orientation of the text..

I tried to insert `android:orientation="horizontal"` in the TableLayout and in the TableRow, but without results. Only if i remove my webViews, the text will be show

Is it an Android 4.3 bug, or i have to insert something in my code? 
I attached my xml file and a link to the screenshot.

----> [Image](http://oi44.tinypic.com/2jc7vwx.jpg)

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- parte superiore (tabs) -->

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dati_imp"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.335"
            android:background="#669900"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dati_imp"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inverter"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.335"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/inverter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cfr_inv"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cfr_inv" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cont_fisc"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cont_fisc" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contatti"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/contatti" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</TableLayout>

<!-- parte inferiore (button) -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:text="@string/refresh_button_label" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- parte centrale -->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dati_gen"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/dati_imp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kwn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dataAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tariffa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/co2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/conto_en"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/conto_en"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oggiEn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/meseEn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/annoEn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totEn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/conto_en_txt"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foto"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/foto"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview_foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pot_imp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/pot_imp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp" >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/potPerc"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarpotenza" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/potTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/potPerc"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stato_imp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/stato_imp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fotostato"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nonatt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pot_tot"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/pot_tot"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/potenza"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxgiorno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxmese"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxanno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prod_tot"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/prod_tot"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oggi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mese"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/anno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prod_tot_k"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/prod_tot_k"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oggiKWp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/meseKWp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/annoKWp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totKWp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cornice8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cornice"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/meteo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/meteo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/Gray" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dp" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview_meteo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:text="@string/info"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### EDIT:

I verified that the orientation of textView change (inserting `android:layout_height="300dp"` in the TableLayout's textViews to see the entire text). Now, how to fix it??

### EDIT2:

In another activity with a layout that contents an ExpandableListview, i have exactly the same problem, and the group indicator, positioned by the code to right, go to the left side of each group item. I repeat, this only in API 18...

### EDIT3: SOLVED

I finally got the solution and attached as new answer! (title changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after going crazy to understand where the problem was, i got the solution!!
I don't know why, but i discovered i had the same issue in all activities that show a TableLayout and 0px width and a weight childs attribute.

Changing something in UI, like loading the WebView(s), or (in another activity), resume activity after a spinner selection, caused the problem.
In the second case i had trouble also in API < 18 (virtual and real) devices, then i realize it was not only an API 18 bug...

I solved my issue only adding a TableLayout attribute in each XML file with the specified TableLayout:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

After adding that in all my TableLayouts, i solved it!

Hope this help =)..